# Create Model object for form submission in MVC framework like Backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, model-view-controller, forms, backbone-views

In a normal web application, we would have a client-side form with multiple fields (e.g. say 10 fields.. field1, field2, etc)

When we submit this form, these 10 fields would automatically get submitted/posted to the server and we can do the processing on the server.

But I wanted to understand how this would work when using a MVC framework like Backbone.JS

1. How do we create the Model object?
2. Is it tied to the View (form) and whatever attributes are in the Model would get posted ?
3. Can we control what fields/attributes get posted to the server (like passing only a subset of the entire Model)

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is that when the user clicks the (e.g.) "save" button, do this:

1. create a javascript object containing all your form's data as attributes (e.g. by using Backbone.Syphon https://github.com/derickbailey/backbone.syphon/);
2. instanciate a new model by passing in your data object (or update an existing one);
3. save the new model instance.

Filtering the attributes that are used is easy: just remove them from the data object you use to create your model instance.

You can see a real example from my [book on Backbone.Marionette](https://leanpub.com/marionette-gentle-introduction):

- when a form is submitted, get the data from the form (see `submitClicked` in https://github.com/davidsulc/marionette-gentle-introduction/blob/master/assets/js/apps/contacts/common/views.js)
- then save the updated data (see the "form:submit" event listener in https://github.com/davidsulc/marionette-gentle-introduction/blob/master/assets/js/apps/contacts/edit/edit_controller.js#L19)

Hope this helps!